# difference between app hub "personal" and "company" account types

Tags: windows-phone-7, app-hub

In app hub, there are two account types "personal" and "company". Can anyone tell we the difference between the two in terms of
1. number of apps submitted to marketplace
2. no of devices unlocked
3. number of apps that can be tested in each device
4. developers share for each app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202924%28v=vs.92%29.aspx):

> 7) Should I select Company, Individual, or Student?
>
> Each of the three account types: Company, Individual, and Student, can
>   publish and sell both paid and free applications. The following
>   outlines which account type you should select when creating your
>   account.
>
> Note:
>   You cannot change the Account type after completing the Registration
>   process.
>
> **Company:** Select Company if you are registering on behalf of a
>   corporation, limited liability company (LLC), partnership, or other
>   company legally registered with your local government. If you do not
>   have a U.S. Employer Identification Number (EIN), then you must send
>   the appropriate W-8 form to Microsoft to receive Windows Phone
>   Marketplace payouts.
>
> **Individual:** Select Individual if you are an individual developer. Your
>   applications sales will contribute to your personal income.
>   Individuals must send the appropriate W-8 form to Microsoft to receive
>   Windows Phone Marketplace payouts.
>
> **Student:** Select Student if you are a student registered with
>   DreamSpark. There is no annual membership fee for student accounts.
>   Students must send the appropriate W-8 form to Microsoft to receive
>   Windows Phone Marketplace payouts.

***There is no difference in terms of any of the points you asked between individual and company account types.***

That means that:
1. The number of apps that can be submitted to the marketplace is the same for all account types. The only restrictino applies to submissions (including updates) of free apps. [99 per year]
2. The number of devices that can be unlocked per account does not differ between personal and company types. For both it defaults to three but you can request more via the support link in the app hub.
3. The number of apps that can be tested in each device is not related to the type of account that was used to unlock the device. I think (from memory) it's 12 for both.
4. The developers share for each app is the same regardless of account type. Microsoft take 30%.

**The only difference is the one highlighted.**

Comment: hi matt. That doesnt answer the questions i asked.

Comment: @MridulRaj I've expanded by what I menat when I said "There is no difference in terms of any of the points you asked between individual and company account types."